# Client does not wait for Server response through grpc-go

Tags: go, grpc-go

I am trying to send a command from client to server using grpc-go. Server receives this command, execute the command (through cmd.Run() which takes few seconds) and if execution is successful returns the status back to client.

I have tried it with unary rpc. Server successfully executes the command but client does not wait for server and immediately throws the following error.

```
2023/10/24 09:06:05 Connection to server successful
2023/10/24 09:06:06 Could not receive response from server: **rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
exit status 1**
```

Does any one know how can I resolve this error?

Comment: It's difficult to help without a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Based on the error it looks like the context (which you pass to the generated function when making the RPC call) is being cancelled (perhaps via `context.WithTimeout`), but we can't really know without access to your code.

Comment: You are correct. I debugged the code yesterday and found that context is cancelled out, so I increased the timeout limit.